# How does accepted answer loses accepted status?

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer

I was reading few guidelines  and and came to a point where it was written that you lose a reputation if an accepted answer loses accepted status.

How and in what case this can be done?

Comment: Mmm huh, finding a dupe for this was harder than I thought . . . #ScatteredMetaInfoFTW

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M Is there any kind of feature available in SE to find the dupe questions.?

Comment: Yes, it's called "search".

Answer (score 7):

> How and in what case this can be done.?

The person who accepted the answer (i.e. the person who asked it) can un-accept it.

A rare possibility is that two questions that have accepted answers get merged - one of the accepted answers will lose the accept status as result (the one from the question being merged, IIRC).

Comment: So in that case OP will loose some reputation. I thought some one else can cancel the accepted status.

Comment: How so? They only lose the reputation originally gained with the accept. Only the question OP can accept/unaccept.

Comment: okay you mean to say -2

Comment: No. If someone accepts your answer, you get 15 rep. If they then un-accept it, those 15 rep are lost. Where did you get the idea of -2?

Comment: I mean to say if I accept an answer, i'll get +2 and it if unaccept it so -2

Comment: @CZAbhinav - yes, that is correct.

Comment: Unless it's a self-answer then no rep is gained or lost. /cc @CZAbhinav.

Comment: Am I right that merging questions loses the accepted status of one of the answers?

Comment: @JanDvorak - oh, yeah. That can happen. Very rare though.